# Starting with the corresponding class tabhost

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-tabhost

My code:

- Main.java
- TabHost.java
- Tab1.java
- Tab2.java
- Tab3.java
- main.xml
- menutab.xml

Within the main.xml have three buttons, which are: btnTab1, btnTab2, btnTab3.

Within the menutab.xml have a tabhost with id = th and the layout of each tab is id = tab1, tab2 = id, id = tab3.

I need for each button click on that person main.xml be verified which was the button, and open its activity in menutab.xml

In short: when the User clicks on the button for example Tab1 will draw the layout menutab.xml and open the corresponding class activity. Each tab is a class activity

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate in Main.java (add a similar bit of code for each button):

```
    Button btnTab1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnTab1);
    btnTab1.setOnClickListener(tab1handler);
```

After onCreate in Main.java (again, add similar code for each button, changing the TabHost.TAB# to the appropriate one for each button):

```
View.OnClickListener tab1handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, TabHost.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("StartTab", Tabhost.TAB1);
        Main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
};
```

In your TabHost.java add:

```
public final int TAB1 = 0;
public final int TAB2 = 1;
public final int TAB3 = 2;
private int StartTab;
```

in the onCreate of your TabHost add:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
StartTab = extras.getInt("StartTab");
```

after you have set up the tabhost:

```
th.setCurrentTab(StartTab);
```

Hope this helps!